# What version of lamp-mariadb and php should I install on WordPress instance?

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, lamp

I am deploying a MySQL database with AWS RDS and a WordPress site on an EC2 instance. I've found this guide on how to do so: [Deploy WordPress with Amazon RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/deploy-wordpress-with-amazon-rds/).

I followed the guide successfully but need to upgrade to the latest PHP version. The guide has me install these dependencies: `sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2 php7.2`

What are the latest versions of the LAMP stack and PHP to install on my new WordPress deployment?

Comment: MariaDB is at 10.6 now. php is at 7.4. (8.1 is also available, but it's pretty new and WP people are still qualifying it for mass deployment.) You use RDS so you don't need the MySQL / MariaDB server stuff on your EC2 instance., so you don't need to install the "M" from "LAMP". All you need is apache2 and php. (the A and P). This is a good guide, especially if you use an Ubuntu VM. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: I appreciate it. I'm not sure why they would have 'lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2' as a dependency for the wordpress install. I'll simply install php7.4. Thank you!